# Python Selenium " 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Even though I have already put geckodriver in there and I restarted my computer, it still prints the same thing.

```
>>>from selenium import webdriver
>>>browser = webdriver.Firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "D:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "D:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 144, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

And an error before that as well! Someone please help a newbie out. [Image of the Path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2pzg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mention the path of the gecko driver executable. Below line will get you some idea.

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="add geckodriver.exe")
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.